# Displaying two login in Keychain Access

Tags: macos, keychain

As per my Question saying, In my Mac OSX, Keychain Access, Displaying two "login"

[image: Look at rounded circle]

And when I am trying to export any certificate from second login then displayed below error.

[image]

Actually I had to change my mac so from the old system, I kept **"login.keychain"** from `~/Library/Keychains/` and add it to my new system and when I opened keychain access then I faced above issue.

Can you guys help me for solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine ? Its an abnormal behaviour.

Comment: Wait I will do and back soon.

Comment: @RoNiT - I did, Same issue.. displaying two login

Comment: Try this, https://discussions.apple.com/message/29385074#29385074